# What to do if an answer doesn't provide the answer you are looking for, but does give you the tools you need to answer it yourself

Tags: discussion, answers

I posted this question last week: [first-order binding kinetics with multiple identical binding sites](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/74395/first-order-binding-kinetics-with-multiple-identical-binding-sites)

The answer given only partially answers the questions I asked, but it did give me the missing information I needed, which means I was able to go on to solve it myself.

What is the proper recourse here? I accepted the answer, but is there an alternative? Should I edit their answer with information about how I solved it to make it more complete? I don't want to just post my own solution and accept that since it seems rude, but I also don't want to leave the information incomplete.

Comment: It is perfectly fine to answer your own question: [Can I answer my own question?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Just credit the answer you used and it will be fine.

Comment: Upvote it. Add your own answer. Or whatever you want. If you want to accept it you can do that too, it's totally your call. Everything you do is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Posting your own solution isn't rude.  It's being extremely helpful to everyone else who'll come along later with the same problem looking for a solution.

If another answer was helpful to you, despite not actually being a complete solution to your problem, then you can upvote it to indicate that it was helpful, despite not being the answer to your question.

Note that if your answer is derived off of another person's answer, you'll want to cite the answer appropriately, otherwise it's plagiarism.

Comment: OK, thanks. I will add my own answer to the thread today.

Answer (score 2):

I'd upvote the other answer. I'd post my own answer *giving it credit*. I'd choose the answer that I feel is most *useful* as the correct one.

[Here's a case](https://superuser.com/questions/281332/is-my-old-crt-flickering-or-is-it-just-me) where I went with another answer as the correct one, despite using a somewhat different solution from the selected answer.

On the other hand [in some cases](https://superuser.com/questions/333617/is-it-normal-for-a-dell-inspiron-530-to-have-is-fan-to-spin-up-3-times-before-i) there's substantially more 'meat' in your own answer, while another answer got you started. I picked my own answer because it was more complete.

So its certainly fine to post your own answer, since it could help others, even if you don't pick it as the correct one. I'd pick the most useful answer for most people as "correct" tho.